# Hibernate automatic queries

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I need to return stream of objects and would like to know if its possible to do it anyhow rather than declaring my own query, that smart queries return only collections is that correct and i would have to add additional logic to actually return stream or there is a way?

```
@Repository
interface OnStreetSubscriptionRepository : JpaRepository<OnStreetSubscription, Long> {


    @Query("FROM OnStreetSubscription")
    fun streamAll(): Stream<OnStreetSubscription>

}
```

Comment: hmm I dont think it is possible.

What is the problem with doing yourCollectionHere.stream()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have the repositories you want to use streamAll() on extend this repository

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface StreamRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

    @CacheQuery
    Stream<T> readAllBy();
}
```

and use readAllBy();